# Groß-/Kleinschreibung von "Er/er" in Arbeitszeugnissen

Tags: pronoun, capitalization

Ich habe heute mein Arbeitszeugnis bekommen und bin über das "Er" gestolpert. Durch das ganze Zeugnis durch wurde "Er" im Bezug auf mich groß geschrieben.

Ich denke mir, dass das eventuell eine Art von Respektsform sein könnte wie "Sie/Du", bin aber ziemlich sicher, dass das mit Personalpronomen nicht funktioniert.

Bevor ich da jetzt aber anrufe und mich zum Affen mache, frag ich lieber noch mal hier nach.

Comment: Kenne ich so auch nur aus der Bibel, wenn Gott gemeint wird, oder sonst wenn der Papst gemeint wird. <g>

Comment: Hattest du eine Stelle als Papst, König oder Kaiser? Dann ist ein großes "E" angebracht. Wenn nicht, nur am Satzanfang. Scheint ein häufiger Fehler zu sein, siehe hier https://www.deutschlandfunk.de/haeufige-fehler-in-arbeitszeugnissen.680.de.html?dram:article_id=34307 oder hier https://www.computerwoche.de/a/die-neun-groessten-zeugnismaengel,2355555,4

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Beim Papst? Und Kaiser haben wir schon lange nicht mehr, das ist schon sprichwörtlich. Der Adel ist abgeschafft. Damit natürlich unangemessene Ehrbekundungen. Wer stellt denn solche Zeugnisse aus? Selbst für eine ironische Andeutung, dass Du dich wie ein Kaiser aufgeführt hast, ist es für meinen Geschmack zu dick aufgetragen. Aber Zeugnisverfasser sehen sich oft außerhalb der Geschichte gestellt, sogar befugt und berufen "zu unserer vollsten Zufriedenheit" zu schreiben.

Comment: @user: Wir in den Niederlanden haben noch einen König, aber würden, soweit ich weiß, nie "Er" (also "Hij") schreiben.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Ich wollte auch keine allgemeingültige Abhängigkeit unterstellen.

Comment: @user: Alles gut. War nicht ganz ernst gemeint.

Comment: Er war Gustaf Adolfs Page oder Hofnarr Karls des Grossen.

Comment: klar! hat Spass gemacht. Keiner wird meinen, dass du dich aufgeführt hast wie der King oder der Papst (oder Gott himself). Vielleicht kriegst du den nächsten job dank eines originellen Arbeitszeugnis'.

Answer (score 3):

Die Höflichkeitsform mit einem großgeschriebenen "Er" ist veraltet. Das (manchmal) so genannte "Erzen" war im 18. und auch im 19. Jahrhundert üblich, wird heute aber nur noch vereinzelt in Dialekten verwendet.

Heutzutage werden als Pronomen der höflichen Anrede nur "Sie" und (in gewissen Situationen) "Du" mitsamt ihren Ableitungen verwendet. Ein großgeschriebenes "Er" im Arbeitszeugnis ist falsch und sollte tatsächlich korrigiert werden.

Comment: Und beim Erzen geht es ja wohl auch um die Rede mit jmd., nicht übre jmd., oder? Also "Bring Er mir mal einen Kaffee" und nicht "Wusstest du, dass Er einen tollen Kaffee kocht?"

Answer (score 0):

Nach den  neuen Regeln zur Rechtschreibung von Duden ist nicht einmal mehr "du" gross zu schreben.

Wie gesagt ist das eine veraltete Höflichkeisform, und das muss dich nicht verletzen. Wenn es dich aber stört, kannst du deinen früheren Arbeitgeber anrufen und ihn bitten, dir ein neues Arbeitszeugnis auszustellen, ohne dich - oder ihn - zum Affen zu machen. Vergiss nicht, Sie gross zu schreiben, falls du ihm eine mail schickst.

Es könnte auch sein, dass der Arbeitgeber gemeint hat, wenn man englisch I (Ich)  gross schreibt, müsse auch Er gross geschrieben werden.

Comment: @IQV: I think it does, as it is now.